# cannot convert to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService':

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hello It s my first time using spring security. Can you please help me!
Here is my console :

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationCtrl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager tn.talan.project003.AuthenticationCtrl.authManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager tn.talan.project003.AuthenticationCtrl.authManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
    ... 53 more
```

my springsecurity.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/authenticate"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url method="GET"
            pattern="/services/users/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url method="POST"
            pattern="/services/users/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/users/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />

    </security:http>

</beans>
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import tn.talan.model.Utilisateur;
import tn.talan.springData.repo.UserRepository;

public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userBean;



    @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            Utilisateur user = userBean.findByLogin(username);
            System.out.println("User : "+user);
            if(user==null){
                System.out.println("User not found");
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
            }
            return user;
        }

}
```

Actually I'm getting a compliation error because is user is of type Utilisateur and not UserDetails

AuthenticationProcessingfilter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import tn.talan.springData.service.TokenUtils;

@Component("authenticationTokenProcessingFilter")
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final UserDetailsService userService;
    private TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(UserDetailsService userService, TokenUtils tokenUtils) {

        this.userService = userService;
        this.tokenUtils = tokenUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting a HTTP request");
        }

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");

        String userName = tokenUtils.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);

        if (userName != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if (tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and finally my Springmvc controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import tn.talan.model.Utilisateur;
import tn.talan.springData.service.TokenUtils;
import tn.talan.springSecurity.configuration.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class AuthenticationCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private  CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenUtils tokenUtils; 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public Utilisateur authenticate(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication authentication = this.authManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        Utilisateur user = (Utilisateur) this.userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        user.setToken(tokenUtils.createToken((UserDetails) user));

        return user;
    }

}
```

Utilisateur.java :my model

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;


/**
 * The persistent class for the USERS database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@NamedQuery(name="Utilisateur.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u")
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long iduser;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String login;

    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String token;

    @Column(name="\"ROLE\"")
    private String role;

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.role);
        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(authority);
        return authorities;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=Agence.class)
    private Agence agence;

    public Utilisateur() {
    }

    public long getIduser() {
        return this.iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(long iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return this.login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Agence getAgence() {
        return agence;
    }

    public void setAgence(Agence agence) {
        this.agence = agence;
    }
    public void setToken(String token){
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken(){
        return token;
    }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>

    </context-param>



    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> 
        classpath:applicationContext.xml </param-value> </context-param> -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <display-name>TalanPFE</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you also add your Utilisateur and CustomUserDetailsService classes?

Comment: is CustomUserDetailsService extends to UserDetailsService?

Comment: Add `@Service("customUserDetailsService")` annotation to your `CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl` class. Without this, spring cannot initialize been of CustomUserDetailsService.

Comment: I added the annotation as you mentionned but I'm getting new exception  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined ! I tried to add extends USerDetailsService but I'm getting error compilation! Please some help!

Comment: I added above  my User Class

Comment: What I did and it works for me - I added a class SecurityUser which extends my user class (in your case - Utilisateur) and at the same time implements UserDetails. You can have a look, hope this could help you somehow https://github.com/lenach87/Ochumailoc

Comment: Hi I tried to change my code and I got rid of  that exceptions But I'm getting a new one dealing with webx.xml java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext  I added above web.xml

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, in my case the problem was in dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: From an exception to another I'm blocked with this exception :Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion.DISABLE_CHECKS" "read")  anyone can help

Comment: Do you have somewhere in your code something like this  @PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, 'read')") (or some analog in xml)? Try commenting the parts which relate to Spring security access (like hasRole) - does the error persist?

Comment: hi it worked fine with me ! I had to add a class UserSecurity Whetre I extended y User model and implemented User details. But Having a new problem now ! How can I get the user return in other controller . I tryed to add A class userBeanSession where I added @Scope("session") But it's not working with me :/ Any hel please

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. What do you mean by "return user in other controller"? Do you in some other place want to know the name of user which is currently logged in?

Comment: yes that's it actually I used HttpServletRequest.getSession() and it worked fine with me . But I m wandering if it s the best methode to do it or there 's another method

Comment: @yeddez I am not sure what approach is the best one. I can suggest another option - you can try it and see if it works for you - add a method to receive information on Principal            'private String getPrincipal(){
        String username = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
        return username;
    } '